# How to use SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy with TimeBasedRollingPolicy in Log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

Hi I am using Log4j for logging. Below is my configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="FileAppender_Comp3" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> 

<rollingPolicy name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
<param name="FileNamePattern" value="log/Comp3_%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss}.log" />
</rollingPolicy> 

<triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="3kb"/>
</triggeringPolicy>

<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
</layout>

</appender>
```

But when I am running file it is throwing below error.

```
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [maxFileSize] to value "3kb".
```

How can I fix this. Please help me.

Comment: Just a guess, but did you try to replace 3kb with 3072? In the JavaDoc (http://goo.gl/ahbl8) I found "Sets rollover threshold size in bytes",  so I think you can't pass the value with KB, MB or another suffix.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936021/rolling-logs-by-size-and-time/14202093#14202093

Comment: @Samurai, have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [Log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), you can specify the size in KB or MB.

Relevant XML below.

```
<Policies>
    <!-- Starts a new log on tomcat start -->
    <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy /> 
    <!--  Starts a new file when size reaches threshold -->
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" /> 
    <!-- causes a rollover once the date/time pattern no longer 
       applies to the active file -->
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy /> 
</Policies
```

Please see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html for more details.

Comment: What if we don't specify KB/MB and just a number `size=10` What would it take default?

Comment: it's either KB, MB, and GB now.

Answer (score 5):

As per documentation, it has to be long value for MaxFileSize. Please check at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html

So, the value should be 3072 instead of 3kb in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more details about how you can specify the size for log4j2:

```
<Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
</Policies>
```

If you check the source code for [file size parsing](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/FileSize.java), the regular expression that is used to parse the value is the following:

```
/**
* Pattern for string parsing.
*/
private static final Pattern VALUE_PATTERN = 
Pattern.compile("([0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?)\\s*(|K|M|G|T)B?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I haven't seen this anywhere in documentation, but basically you can either specify a number (then it will denote a total number of bytes), or use KB,MB,GB,TB to specify units of measurement. Also you can use fractional numbers and have a whitespace between the number and the unit. The units are case-insensitive, so it should be possible to specify kb, or KB.

Answer (score 1):

The size-based trigger won't work unless you add "%i" to FileNamePattern. Otherwise the filename doesn't change so the size-based trigger does not cause a roll.

(in addition to the already-mentioned MaxFileSize being a long "bytes" value without units)

One good source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-rolling-file-appenders#5-rolling-based-on-size-and-time

Answer (score 0):

just happened to come across this question and thought I should share the solution:

set the MaxFileSize param to a value in bytes, so for your example you would set it as

```
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="3072"/>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157371/unable-to-set-maxfilesize-to-value-100mb-in-log4j) is a similar question where this solution is confirmed.